# Incorrect page coding? Articles does not accept "polish characters" like ąęćżź

Tags: html, character-encoding

I have problem with my page. Since 1 or 2 months I have problem with the coding (probably). Look how it looks as an admin.

[image]

And how it looks when you enter the page

[image]

Comment: it's a typeface problem, not all fonts cover the same utf8 characters

Comment: It's a font problem. You can try using the <pre>....</pre> tag to show the text as it is.